# Safe write to file from stdout?

Tags: linux, command-line, pipe

Ordinarily typing `cmd > file` will overwrite the file if it already exists. I often type `>>` to append, but get very worried about accidentally typing `>` and destroying my file. Is there an alternative command which doesn't risk me destroying a file if I mistype? Or alternatively, a way to make `>` ask for permission before overwriting existing files?

Comment: [Solution for `bash`](https://superuser.com/a/1410516/432690).

Comment: @Kamil thank you! I use suckless terminal rather than bash, so this doesn't solve my problem completely, but is definitely a useful place to look

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is. Just in case: [*What is the difference between Terminal, Console, Shell, and Command Line?*](https://askubuntu.com/q/506510/693277)

Comment: Got it, I'm an idiot! I thought st was a shell and didn't read from `bashrc`, but I've just looked and I'm wrong. Thank you!